# How to encrypt the challenge phrase and answer for OpenAM Lost Password Management?

Tags: openam

I recently had to convert challenge questions and passwords for an OpenAM implementation.

The plan was to convert these values as part of the user entry in a LDIF file and load it. The attribute to complete is `iplanet-am-user-password-reset-question-answer`. This is a multi valued attribute to support multiple question/answer pairs.

The challenge question key, answer and question key and question status flag had to be combined in a single line delimited by tabs.

```
[question-key]\t[answer]\t[1|0]
```

The value needs to be encrypted.  This was the class used to encrypt but it did not work.

```
AMPasswordUtil().encrypt(question.get(challenge) + "\t" + response + "\t1")
```

What to do  to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Finally gave up and dropped ForgeRock support a question. They were very helpful and supplied the solution and it worked immediately.  Here it is...

It turns out the `AMPasswordUtil` class should not be used.  Instead this should be used

```
encrypted_str = AccessController.doPrivileged(new EncodeAction( clear_text_str ))
```

The encryption key needs to be set as a system property

```
System.setProperty("am.encryption.pwd", key );
```

The encryption key can be retrieved from OpenAM.

Comment: Another option would be to use 'ampassword' utility of 'ssoadm' tool set as this does basically the same, but is 'supported'.

`ampassword -e ....`

Comment: Yes, could have, that was the fall back plan but then I would have had to execute that in the shell and get it back into the conversion program.